# How can I run a method asynchronously in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous, google-apps-script

I have a function that's called by the client when some data is submitted via a form. This triggers an action that sends an email out to individuals that wish to receive notifications. The problem is that this has to be done synchronously with the form submit, so the user submitting the form has to wait for the emails to be sent before they receive the return data from Apps Script saying that the submission was successful.

This can sometimes take several seconds. Is there a way to asynchronously run a function in apps script (So the server can return a message to the client while the emails are being sent)?

Or even better, create an event that I can listen to similar to events in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title is misleading. you don't want it to run async, which it will by default when you make a call like google.script.run.somefunction() from the client side.

What you need to do is, create another function within the apps script, (say EmailSentSuccessfully()), which reports true/false based on whether the email has finished sending. It could read a 'Property' (essentially a static global variable) which is updated by the function that actually sends the email. You call EmailSentSuccessfully() from your client, say every 2 seconds, till it returns a true value. Till that time, do nothing, (or disable form elements so the user cannot take any other action).

Comment: It does not run async on the server side: Client submits --> server verifies --> server writes to database --> server sends emails --> returns true/false/message to client. What I want is to return true/false/message to the client before it tries to send the emails, the success of the form submit should not be dependent on the emails being successfully sent. In .NET I would just make an event that fires, so listeners/subscribers can run while a message is returned and the user doesn't need to wait so long for a success message.

Comment: That being said, writing the submission info to a script property (Apps script does not support persistent global variables), and running a function every minute (lowest timeframe for a time based trigger) will definitely work.

Comment: what is the meaning of the "true" or "false" if the emails haven't been sent?

Comment: Sorry  if that wasn't clear. The true/false/message is if it successfully wrote the submission data to the pseudo-database, a fusion table. There are a number of reasons why it would fail, from auth/permission issues, a bad query, invalid input...etc Some of these will return before trying to send an email as false or with a message that it failed, but a success message (just `true`) has to wait for the emails to send before it can return. As for the emails, the submitter doesn't need to know if they where sent or not, it doesn't apply to them.